# How to make a timer in java?

Tags: java

I want to make a timer that counts up rather than down. Is there a way I could do this? I have no code on this so far. But I have found some code that ticks down but not up. I did see something in the api about "timer" but I have no clue about it. I have read things about it but still do not understand it at all.

Comment: Search something on the net, implement some code and then if it' not working ask us.

Comment: is it homework ?  timer is related to time. Perhaps you only want a counter ? what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Let it count from *N* to *0*. Suppose *n* is the current value. Your positive counter *n'* has to be *N-n*. That's all. No need for a counter that goes on the other direction.

Example:

```
N = n = 5 => n' = 5-5 = 0
N = 5, n = 4 => n' = 5-4 = 1
...
N = 5, n = 1 => n' = 5-1 = 4
N = 5, n = 0 => n' = 5-0 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Swing and `JLabel` and update the counter there. 
Try this code. [check this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/a-simple-timer-example/)

```
 public class Counter {
    private static int cnt;

 public static void main(String args[]) {

  ActionListener actListner = new ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    cnt += 1;
    System.out.println("Counter = "+cnt);

}

  };

  Timer timer = new Timer(1000, actListner);
  timer.start();
    }
  }
```